# How to add wizard shortcut in a view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to put wizard shortcuts in my view for my product as seen in screenshot below. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper` does this - an internal class so it should not be used. You could look at the source to see what it does.

Comment: @greg-449 You do a great job helping people by answering questions about Eclipse for years! I like to [nominate you here](https://www.eclipse.org/org/foundation/eclipseawards/). But I would need at least your e-mail address. To do so, please send me an e-mail to my address you find in Bugzilla. I guess it would not be a problem to stay anonymous, only what name to engrave on the award and where to send it would need to be known. Did you know that they would have given you an award some time ago, but didn't know how to contact you?

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you! Can you please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution?

Comment: @howlger I agree!

Comment: @howlger Hi, yes I remember someone asked me some time ago. As I said then I much prefer to just stay as low profile as possible.

Comment: @greg-449 I see. Like Batman and other superheroes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Explorer, Package Explorer and the old Resource navigator all use `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper` to display this.

Since that is an internal class it is not part of the official API so should not be used directly, but you could study the source code to see what it does.